# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP maven project

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets

I have created a Maven web based project. but when i am running the JSP file i m getting below exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for      the arguments (void)
1: <html>
2: <body>
3: <h2><% int i = 0;  %>Hello World!<%=out.println(i) %></h2>
4: </body>
5: </html>


Stacktrace:
   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
```

I have not included the servlet api jar, Please find the attached structure

[image]

Please help.

Comment: why you didn't include servlet api??

Comment: <%= %> already print value of expression. Try just like this <%=i%> or just out.print(i). Both is equivalent.

Comment: @Migrated Pigeon Tomcat already have this, If i include this again then it conflict

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt  this is not the case of wrong syntex, JSP is not compiling...

Comment: The solution @Gurkan Yesilyurt said looks good to me.